# Is there a word for someone who would be a single-issue voter, even if not eligible to vote?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, politics

I'm 16 years old, so (at least where I am) I can't vote yet. If I could vote, I would be a "single-issue voter"; there is one political issue that is, to me, more important than any other. Is there a word or phrase for someone like me, who would be a single-issue voter, but can't vote?

Example:

> Joe, a [this word or phrase], believes that [issue] is the most important political issue in [country] today, but is not eligible to vote, so he donates to [political organization] instead.

Comment: Dear 16-year old: I believe you have it. A single issue-voter. If I were your age, I most definitely but not donate to political parties/entities. Only to environmental ones. Cheers.

Comment: ...unless your party is a [single-issue party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-issue_politics). The first *[this word or phrase]* is sometimes **minor** although the definition varies by jurisdiction.

Comment: @WeatherVane "minor" doesn't imply having single-issue opinions. The scenario would be the same if I was an adult non-naturalized immigrant. And no, I'm not a member of a single issue party (I've already registered to vote).

Comment: Indeed "minor" implies too young to vote, sorry if that was unclear. I don't know a word for "a single-issue supporter who is too young to vote" and the sample sentence isn't phrased as though there is. If such a word is supposed to go in the [first placeholder] the sentence repeats what was already said.

Comment: *Joe is a [this word or phrase] so he donates to [political organization].*

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for a variation on *single-issue voter*?  This term doesn't have a lot of meaning outside of describing voting habits.  It describes a person who will vote for a party or candidate because of their stance on this one issue, and regardless of their stances on other issues.  E.g. a single-issue voter whose single issue is making abortion illegal may vote for an anti-abortion candidate, even if the single-issue voter does not agree with the candidate's stances on the environment, taxation, immigration, etc.

Comment: @Juhasz you just described by political beliefs perfectly.

Comment: @Juhasz but I'm looking for a word that would also apply e.g. to someone whose issue was fighting climate change or reducing taxes.

Comment: A would-be single-issue voter.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't imply that you can't vote, but **single issue supporter** seems apt:

> I don’t care about the rest of his platform. I’m a single issue supporter now. I support all candidates that support #Reparations regardless of party.
> — [@thedrhistorian on Twitter](https://twitter.com/tariqnasheed/status/1528040421418364928?lang=en)

> The Matthew Shepard and James Byrd, Jr. Hate Crimes Prevention Act is now law, but Shepard is not a single-issue supporter of the gay community.
> — [Obama and the Gays: A Political Marriage](https://books.google.com/books?id=KgB0pfSYbj8C&pg=PA481&lpg=PA481&dq=%22single%20issue%20supporter%22&source=bl&ots=WlIZmqLTBp&sig=ACfU3U0mtvP4l9AW2TA2x_fcGkASSeyZLw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk0MSiqeD6AhWDMVkFHfhdAr8Q6AF6BAgXEAI)

There are, of course, many reasons why a person might not be able to vote: too young, not a resident, being convicted of a crime — or even not being a white landowning man in the US in ages past. In the quote from *Obama and the Gays*, it seems like Shepard does vote (when there's an election), but is going above and beyond to get multiple bits of legislation adopted.